# is there some way to do this sql script, in mysql?

Tags: mysql

This script was make in postgres, but I don't find their way to make it in mysql

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'example_work_db') THEN
    CREATE USER example_work_srv WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'P4ssw0rd.';
    GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE example_work_db TO example_work_srv;
    GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO example_work_srv;
  END IF;
  IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'example_test_db') THEN
    CREATE USER example_test_srv WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'P4ssw0rd.';
    GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE example_test_db TO example_test_srv;
    GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO example_test_srv;
  END IF;
  IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'example_live_db') THEN
    CREATE USER example_live_srv WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'P4ssw0rd.';  
    GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE example_live_db TO example_live_srv;
    GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO example_live_srv;
  END IF;
END
$do$;
```

Thank you in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is similar in structure, the details are different.

for compatibility reasons i selected natve password.

But there are more authentication method, so you should check the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html) and choose one which fits your server.

Depe3nding on the setup of the server `'example_work_srv'@'localhost'` is not enough, because it allows only access from the local computer, please see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/access-control.html) for more informnation

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `testdb`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_new:user` ()
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'example_work_db') THEN
  CREATE USER 'example_work_srv'@'localhost'
  IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'P4ssw0rd';
    GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON example_work_db.* TO 'example_work_srv'@'localhost';
  END IF;
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'example_test_db') THEN
    CREATE USER 'example_test_srv'@'localhost'
  IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'P4ssw0rd.';
   GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON example_test_db.* TO 'example_test_srv'@'localhost';
  END IF;
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'example_live_db') THEN
    CREATE USER 'example_live_srv'@'localhost'
  IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'P4ssw0rd.';  
    GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON example_live_srv.*  TO 'example_live_srv'@'localhost';
  END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: many thanks for your reply @nbk, I tested this script, and I believe that is the best option, because I used this script with flyway-jenkins migration, and it works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You should only change create and grant statements, everything else is ok.

```
CREATE USER example_work_srv IDENTIFIED BY 'P4ssw0rd.';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON public.* TO example_work_srv;
```

Comment: This reply, I consider that is best, if it work in a localhost environment, however I need for many environments (work, test and live), so thank you very much!